# Limit Quiz Time Setting

Tags: moodle

I want to limit the time for quiz, allowing the time to be set between 11.00 am - 5.00 pm only.

I found this line:
**lib/form/datetimeselector.php**
On function _createElement, Line 120: I change the value 23 to 11

Now the open time options are limited to 11, but this also affected the close time.

And it is also affected all module.

Please point me to correct place to modify the time option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the solution

### **Simple steps**

1. Duplicate `lib/form/datetimeselector.php` into 2 new copies and rename those 2 copies as `datetimeselector_quizopen.php` and `datetimeselector_quizopen.php`
2. In those two files, change the class name and the function name (legacy constructor) accordingly.
3. On Line 131, in both files, change the value of `for loop` accordingly.
4. Register both files ini `lib/formslib.php` (Line 3227)
5. In `mod/quiz/mod_form.php`, change the element name from `date_time_selector` to `date_time_selector_quizopen` (Line 86) and `date_time_selector_quizclose` (Line 90)

### **Detail steps**

1. Go to folder `lib/form` and duplicate `datetimeselector.php` - 2 copies
2. Rename the first copy as `datetimeselector_quizopen.php`
3. Rename the second copy as `datetimeselector_quizclose.php`
4. In `datetimeselector_quizopen.php`, rename the class name from `MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector` to `MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizopen` (Line 42)
5. In the same file, rename function name from `public function MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector` to public `function MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizopen` (Line 115)
6. In the same file, change from `for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {` to `for ($i = 11; $i <= 16; $i++) {` (Line 131)
7. In `datetimeselector_quizclose.php`, rename the class name from `MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector` to `MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizclose` (Line 42)
8. In the same file, rename function name from `public function MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector` to public `function MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizclose` (Line 115)
9. In the same file, change from `for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {` to `for ($i = 11; $i <= 16; $i++) {` (Line 131)
10. Go to file lib/formslib.php, Line 3227 - or search `MoodleQuickForm::registerElementType('date_time_selector'` - add this code:

    MoodleQuickForm::registerElementType('date_time_selector_quizopen', "$CFG->libdir/form/datetimeselector_quizopen.php", 'MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizopen');
    MoodleQuickForm::registerElementType('date_time_selector_quizclose', "$CFG->libdir/form/datetimeselector_quizclose.php", 'MoodleQuickForm_date_time_selector_quizclose');
11. Go to `mod/quiz/mod_form.php`, Line 86, change from `$mform->addElement('date_time_selector', 'timeopen',` to `$mform->addElement('date_time_selector_quizopen', 'timeopen',`
12. In the same file, Line 90, change from `$mform->addElement('date_time_selector', 'timeclose',` to `$mform->addElement('date_time_selector_quizclose', 'timeclose',`